# Python: calling function inside a class inside a route from another file

Tags: python

I am a complete Python newbie and am trying to add functionality to an existing code base (for complete reference, it is [airnotifier](http://airnotifier.github.io) - which is an open source push server. It's missing functionality which I am adding)

Here is the situation:
I have a python file **api/tokens.py** that has this:

```
@route(r"/api/v2/tokens/([^/]+)")
class TokenV2HandlerGet(APIBaseHandler):
    def delete(self, token):
        """Delete a token
        """
```

This was mapped to a route because it is actually invoked from the UI to delete a given token

I now have another file **pushservices/apns.py**
that I've extended to perform certain feedback checks that are missing in the code base and now I need to be able to delete a token. How do I invoke the function above from pushservices/apns.py?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#general format
from your.package.name import some_delete_function

@route(r"/api/v2/tokens/([^/]+)")
class TokenV2HandlerGet(APIBaseHandler):
    def delete(self, token):
        """Delete a token
        """
        some_delete_function(arg1,arg2,etc)

#assuming all of this is in the same parent dir
from pushservices import apns as some_delete_function
```

Comment: Thank you. So I want to invoke the delete function in your answer from apns.py. So in apns.py I added from api.tokens import delete as mydelete (where this delete function exists) hoping I could call mydelete in apns.py but that seems to conflict with other modules - python exits with errors. Can you expand your answer a little bit or alternately, tell me how I could invoke within apns.py a http post that invokes that url in @route?

Comment: could you add the error you got and the base file structure of your project to the question?   The general problem you are having is common, but fix is always in the details.

Comment: Here goes https://gist.github.com/pliablepixels/232f27eb9a32420c38dc
To add some context: What I am really  trying to do is delete a token. The UI already has a route to do this that the template calls. What I am hoping to do is call that function programmatically from another part of my code - so if there is a better way to do it fine. In essence, if I can get a handle to  the db which is set up in https://github.com/airnotifier/airnotifier/blob/master/airnotifier.py#L200 then I can hit the DB directly as well

Comment: while you were putting your gist together, i was putting this together.  I'll look at your gist, but this might make it obvious for you: https://github.com/tlastowka/sample_yourproject

Comment: Thanks - I went over your example several times. I think I might not have explained where I am trying to make the changes - my project is actually apns.py in your example. I'm trying to invoke the delete function in tokens.py in your example (which is in a different directory). Would you mind taking a look at my gist? It's entirely possible your github project is similar to what I need - but I can't seem to get it yet. And it's incredibly awesome of you to post that github sample!

Comment: Looking at your gist, you need to access the function delete of the class TokenV2HandlerGet.  That function references the class itself, so you can't import it on its own because its only going to work in the context of the class its attached to.  You could define a new class that inherits from the original one and adds the functionality you want to the delete function or adds a second delete function, and then use that class in your project instead of the original one

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally went the route of passing a handle to the DB and I directly deleted the token from the DB, but am accepting your answer as it's correct as well. I realized later that the reason I was facing errors because importing api into apns was causing issues as apns was already importing from api and I did not know enough of python to resolve it (and this is unrelated to the question I was asking)